# Supervisorctl worker.log error : Could not open input file: /Users/../ artisan

Tags: php, supervisord, laravel-9

Laravel worker cant execute the command artisan queue:work but the status show the worker is running,i know something is wrong about the command in the supervisord command but cant figure it out .

```
    My supervisord.conf file:
    [program:laravel-worker]
    process_name=%(program_name)s\_%(process_num)02d

    command=/opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/ricky/Documents/Project/Blog/ artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stopasgroup=true
    killasgroup=true
    numprocs=2
    redirect_stderr=true
    stdout_logfile=/Users/ricky/Documents/Project/Blog/worker.log
    stopwaitsecs=3600
    startsecs = 0
    stopasgroup=true
    stopsignal=QUIT


    supervisor status
    laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 98925, uptime 0:00:00
    laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01   RUNNING   pid 98924, uptime 0:00:00
    
    worker.log file shows error
    Could not open input file: /Users/ricky/Documents/Project/Blog/artisan..
```

Answer (score 0):

Your supervisor is unable to find artisan

```
command=/opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/ricky/Documents/Project/Blog/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
```

You just had an extra space, you can always test it out by running the command in the terminal directly to see if it runs, then edit the file, so in the terminal run:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/ricky/Documents/Project/Blog/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
```

Make sure you use the absolute path to the folder.